# Calling a method on DataBound field 's DataField

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, controls

I want to call a method on databound field on datafield. e.g.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="TitlePLang"  HeaderText="Batch Title"  /> This is simple bound field but I want to do something like this.

<asp:BoundField DataField='<%# Eval(getCultureSpecificTitle("TitlePLang","TitleSLang",true))%>'  HeaderText="Batch Title"  />
```

Where getCultureSpecificTitle is a method in code behind, but its giving error that bound field doesn't allow data binding.

So please help how can I do this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is not possible using the bind files but you can make use of the `TempalteField` avaialbe in the grid view will allows you to do this easily.

If you want to achieve same from the code behind than you make use of `OnRowDataBound` event available for the datagrid view will do the work for you.

Comment: .. i did get the boundfield and sets its datafield property there.

Comment: @vickyshazad- but you cannot specify the expression there you can do it in rowbound event or with the template field you can achieve that